# Far side general perspective / custom orthographic projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'd like to create a map with a far side general perspective as shown on the right:

[image: wiki_general_perspectives]

Unsure if relevant but I'd also like to orient the perspective from GPS coordinates and zoom in, creating a realistic view of a continent without compressing edges as much. Extremities of the projection / view aren't of concern.

I'm using QGIS 3.10 but can't find documentation on how to do this. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, using an [azimuthal equidistant](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/azimuthal-equidistant.htm) projection, labelled "stereographic" in above pic. Centered over Guatemala (adjust `+lat_0=14 +lon_0=-90`):

`+proj=aeqd +lat_0=14 +lon_0=-90 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`

Hope this helps someone.